# RxAndroid - using RxView.touches clears other handlers

Tags: kotlin, rx-android

I am trying to add touch handler to [FabricView](https://github.com/antwankakki/FabricView), but it seems that doing so I am not able to sketch any more. Indeed, the FabricView itself defines a Touch handler, but it seems that my attempt - using RxAndroid2 - clears the predefined handler, instead of chaining to it.

What I would like is to be able to use my handler, without clearing the existing one.

This is a portion of my main activity (sketchview is an instance of FabricView)

```
sketchView.backgroundMode = FabricView.BACKGROUND_STYLE_NOTEBOOK_PAPER
    RxView.touches(sketchView, {_ -> true}).subscribe { // setting to false let me sketch, but I don't get any toast
        event -> when(event.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                toast("Starting")
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                toast("Stopping")
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }
```

This is an extract from my app.gradle :

```
compile 'com.github.antwankakki:FabricView:latest'
compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:7.0.0'
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0"
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
```

And in order to use FabricView, we must include JitPack in the allProjects part of the root gradle build.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

This is [the page of the FabricView source code](https://github.com/antwankakki/FabricView/blob/master/src/main/java/com/agsw/FabricView/FabricView.java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RxView.touches()` returns you a [`ViewTouchObservable`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/view/ViewTouchObservable.java) which calls `view.setOnTouchListener(listener)` on subscription to observe the touch events.

> **Warning:** The created observable uses `View.setOnTouchListener()` to observe touches. Only one observable can be used for a view at a time.

Like this your binding the touch events absolutely to this observable. It returns `true` and therefore `onTouchEvent()` won't be called. To use both behaviors you might need to rewrite `ViewTouchObservable` a little and return `false` instead.

Comment: Got a problem when trying to adapt code : with the line 11 `import static com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.internal.Preconditions.checkMainThread;` Indeed it's internal to the Jake Wharton implementation.

Comment: You could inline it or try to ignore the `RestrictTo` part.

Comment: Thanks. Going on implementing your solution.